Recommended Portable Solar Power station for Office Located upon an RV?
I am planning to setup an Ofice with 2 20'' display and a PC upon an RV:
The Displays are:

BenQ BL2283"
LG 22MP55HQ

Whereas my PC specs are:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz
16GB ram
AMD RX550
1 SSD Driver
1 HDD (spinning magnetic)
PSU is a Corsair CX550

And I want to power it offgrid for at least 16Hrs. I will setup the solar power upon an RV. What are your recommendations?
I also havbe a 700VA UPS where I connected 1 screen and my PC tower to it.
